# Dynamically change view of tabs in a QTabWidget (PyQt)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

What i want to do is dynamically add Tabs to a QTabWidget , where each tab is containing either a listView , TableView or some widget and assign them to a model which will control the data to be displayed. The number of Tabs is decided by the number of outputs of another function and the data decides what type of view the tab is going to contain.

Now the problem that i am facing is that how do i put the view in the tab dynamically during execution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add pages dynamically using `addTab`. Have a look at the [QTabWidget reference documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtablewidget.html). Adding [lists](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlistwidget.html) or [tables](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtablewidget.html) is just a case of creating the widgets and adding them to the page.

Here's a quick example:

```
import sys, random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TabContainer(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(TabContainer, self).__init__()
    self.next_item_is_table = False
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry( 150, 150, 650, 350)
    self.tabwidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(self.tabwidget)
    self.setLayout(vbox)
    self.pages = []
    self.add_page()
    self.show()

  def create_page(self, *contents):
    page = QtGui.QWidget()
    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    for c in contents:
        vbox.addWidget(c)

    page.setLayout(vbox)
    return page

  def create_table(self):
    rows, columns = random.randint(2,5), random.randint(1,5)
    table = QtGui.QTableWidget( rows, columns )
    for r in xrange(rows):
        for c in xrange(columns):
            table.setItem( r, c, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem( str( random.randint(0,10) ) ) )
    return table

  def create_list(self):
    list = QtGui.QListWidget()
    columns = random.randint(2,5)
    for c in xrange(columns):
        QtGui.QListWidgetItem( str( random.randint(0,10) ), list )

    return list

  def create_new_page_button(self):
    btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Create a new page!')
    btn.clicked.connect(self.add_page)
    return btn

  def add_page(self):
    if self.next_item_is_table:
        self.pages.append( self.create_page( self.create_table(), self.create_new_page_button() ) )
        self.next_item_is_table = False
    else:
        self.pages.append( self.create_page( self.create_list(), self.create_new_page_button() ) )
        self.next_item_is_table = True

    self.tabwidget.addTab( self.pages[-1] , 'Page %s' % len(self.pages) )
    self.tabwidget.setCurrentIndex( len(self.pages)-1 )

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = TabContainer()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The adding of tab's is the small part. Lets say if each tab has to be populated with a Table View or List View , how would i accomplish that . This is the real problem that i'm facing.

Comment: Adding tables or lists follows the same process, just create the widgets and add them to the page. See my updated answer.