# Add plus button to TabWidget pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, button, pyqt, qtabwidget

The following code gives a tab interface which can dynamically add tabs

```
 import sys, random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TabContainer(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(TabContainer, self).__init__()
    self.next_item_is_table = False
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry( 150, 150, 650, 350)
    self.tabwidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(self.tabwidget)
    self.setLayout(vbox)
    self.pages = []
    self.add_page()
    self.show()

  def create_page(self, *contents):
    page = QtGui.QWidget()
    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    for c in contents:
        vbox.addWidget(c)

    page.setLayout(vbox)
    return page

  def create_table(self):
    rows, columns = random.randint(2,5), random.randint(1,5)
    table = QtGui.QTableWidget( rows, columns )
    for r in xrange(rows):
        for c in xrange(columns):
            table.setItem( r, c, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem( str( random.randint(0,10) ) ) )
    return table

  def create_list(self):
    list = QtGui.QListWidget()
    columns = random.randint(2,5)
    for c in xrange(columns):
        QtGui.QListWidgetItem( str( random.randint(0,10) ), list )

    return list

  def create_new_page_button(self):
    btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Create a new page!')
    btn.clicked.connect(self.add_page)
    return btn

  def add_page(self):
    if self.next_item_is_table:
        self.pages.append( self.create_page( self.create_table(), self.create_new_page_button() ) )
        self.next_item_is_table = False
    else:
        self.pages.append( self.create_page( self.create_list(), self.create_new_page_button() ) )
        self.next_item_is_table = True

    self.tabwidget.addTab( self.pages[-1] , 'Page %s' % len(self.pages) )
    self.tabwidget.setCurrentIndex( len(self.pages)-1 )

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = TabContainer()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I want to add a new tab button next to the tab bar similar to any browser...
I searched for it but I wasn't able to find any way to add a plus button...Is there any property in the TabWidget or do I need to add a new button over there..?

The source for the above code is : [Dynamically change view of tabs in a QTabWidget (PyQt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061611/dynamically-change-view-of-tabs-in-a-qtabwidget-pyqt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a [corner-widget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#setCornerWidget) on the tab-bar:

```
    self.tabButton = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
    self.tabButton.setText('+')
    font = self.tabButton.font()
    font.setBold(True)
    self.tabButton.setFont(font)
    self.tabwidget.setCornerWidget(self.tabButton)
    self.tabButton.clicked.connect(self.add_page)
```